# Asynchronously unit testing a Sanic app throws RuntimeError: this event loop is already running

Tags: python, asynchronous, pytest, aiohttp, sanic

I have a Sanic app that makes some async calls to an external api. I wish to write some unit tests which mock these external calls.

In the code below the tests do pass as we can see from the logs. However after they have completed a RuntimeError: this event loop is already running is thrown

Simplified Sanic app:

```
app = Sanic(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('/usr/src/app/config.py')
Initialize(
    app,
    access_token_name='jwt',
    authenticate=lambda: True,
    claim_aud=app.config.AUTH_JWT_TOKEN['service']['audience'],
    claim_iss=app.config.AUTH_JWT_TOKEN['service']['issuer'],
    public_key=app.config.AUTH_JWT_TOKEN['service']['secret'],
    responses_class=JWTResponses
)


@app.listener('before_server_start')
def init(app, loop):
    ssl_ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain(app.config.SSL_CERT, app.config.SSL_CERT_KEY)
    ssl_ctx.load_verify_locations(app.config.SSL_SERVER_CERT)
    ssl_ctx.check_hostname = False
    ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl_context=ssl_ctx)
    app.aiohttp_session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=conn)
    access_logger.disabled = True


@app.listener('after_server_stop')
def finish(app, loop):
    loop.run_until_complete(app.aiohttp_session.close())
    loop.close()


@app.route("endpoint/<mpn>")
@protected()
async def endpoint(request, mpn):
    msg = msg(
        mpn,
    )
    headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
    async with session.post(
        config.URL,
        data=msg.tostring(pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8'),
        headers=headers,
    ) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
        try:
            response = (
                Response.from_xml(response_text)
            )
            return response
        except ResponseException:
            logger.error(e.get_message()['errors'][0]['message'])
            return response.json(
                e.get_message(),
                status=HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

And here is the test:

```
from server import app as sanic_app


@pytest.yield_fixture
def app():
    app = sanic_app
    yield app


@pytest.fixture
def test_cli(loop, app, sanic_client):
    return loop.run_until_complete(sanic_client(app))


token = jwt.encode(
    {
        "iss": (
            sanic_app.config.AUTH_JWT_TOKEN['service']
            ['issuer']
        ),
        "aud": (
            sanic_app.config.AUTH_JWT_TOKEN['service']
            ['audience']
        ),
        "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(
            seconds=int(100)
        )
    },
    sanic_app.config.AUTH_JWT_TOKEN['service']['secret'],
    algorithm='HS256'
).decode('utf-8')
token = 'Bearer ' + token


async def test_success(test_cli):
    with aioresponses(passthrough=['http://127.0.0.1:']) as m:
        with open('tests/data/summary.xml') as f:
            data = f.read()
        m.post(
            'https://external_api',
            status=200,
            body=data
        )
        resp = await test_cli.get(
            'endpoint/07000000000',
            headers={"Authorization": token}
        )
        assert resp.status == 200
        resp_json = await resp.json()
        assert resp_json == {SOME_JSON}
```

As mentioned above the test does pass but then the error is thrown.

```
================================================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at teardown of test_success ____________________________________________________________________________________

tp = <class 'RuntimeError'>, value = None, tb = None

    def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):
        try:
            if value is None:
                value = tp()
            if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
                raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>           raise value
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py:693:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py:693: in reraise
    raise value
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py:693: in reraise
    raise value
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_sanic/plugin.py:212: in sanic_client
    loop.run_until_complete(client.close())
uvloop/loop.pyx:1451: in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
    ???
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_sanic/utils.py:230: in close
    await self._server.close()
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_sanic/utils.py:134: in close
    await trigger_events(self.after_server_stop, self.loop)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_sanic/utils.py:25: in trigger_events
    result = event(loop)
server.py:84: in finish
    loop.run_until_complete(app.aiohttp_session.close())
uvloop/loop.pyx:1445: in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
    ???
uvloop/loop.pyx:1438: in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
    ???
uvloop/loop.pyx:1347: in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_forever
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

>   ???
E   RuntimeError: this event loop is already running.

uvloop/loop.pyx:448: RuntimeError
```

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should never have to touch the loop, sanic is already running one (which is why you have this error) and pytest also have a plugin that will handle this for you [pytest-asyncio](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio). You test should just import yout `app` then call `app.run(...)` and finally run all tests (request/response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also unregister the call to `after_server_stop` on your `test_cli`:

```
test_cli.server.after_server_stop = []
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix your bug by changing this method:

```py
@app.listener('after_server_stop')
async def finish(app, loop):
    await app.aiohttp_session.close()
```

That's not your responsibility to close the loop and you should use the fact that `finish` is called from an asynchronous context (you don't need to start the event loop, it's already running).

If that's not the only problem, then maybe start from a simpler example and add things until it breaks again. Sanic looks to have a well documented [test section](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/testing.html#testing) where they suggest to use [pytest-sanic](https://github.com/yunstanford/pytest-sanic). A simple example using pytest would look like:

```py
# file: server.py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()

@app.route('/')
async def test(request):
    return json({'hello': 'world'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

```py
# file: server_test.py
import pytest
from server import app

@pytest.yield_fixture
def sanic_app():
    yield app

@pytest.fixture
def test_cli(loop, sanic_app, sanic_client):
    return loop.run_until_complete(sanic_client(app))

async def test_index(test_cli):
    resp = await test_cli.get('/')
    assert resp.status == 200
    json = await resp.json()
    assert json == {'hello': 'world'}

async def test_index_fail(test_cli):
    resp = await test_cli.get('/')
    assert resp.status == 200
    json = await resp.json()
    assert json == {'bonjour': 'monde'}
```

You would need to install some packages:

```
pip install sanic pytest pytest-sanic
```

Then you could just run `pytest`, you should have the first test passing and the second failing.

In general you shouldn't have to start an event loop yourself, always try to get rid of the `loop.run_...`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have been trying to follow the pytest-sanic docs. I believe the problem is caused by the use of aioresponses. This is used to mock the request to the external api. However I think it too creates its own event loop so I need to find away for the Sanic_app and the mock request to interact in the same event loop

Comment: I don't know, maybe you're right. The best thing you could do is to provide the simplest possible example that crashes (and give the whole code so anyone can try to find the bug in a few seconds). Have you tried replacing the code I proposed? Where does it crashes when you do so?

Comment: Hi, one of the sanic core-devs here. I agree with @cglacet that you should avoid  trying to run your loop where you can. Is `sanic_client` an instance of `sanic.testing.SanicTestClient`? I am also a big fan of using `pytest-asyncio` wrappers on my tests, and using that loop.